# Minimisers and critical points of variational integrals

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

In the following we consider $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n\ (n\geq2)$ to be open, bounded and with Lipschitz boundary. Consider the following regular variational integral:
\begin{equation*}
I[u]=\int_{\Omega}f(x, u, Du)\ \mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation*}for all $u$ in the admissible class $W^{1, n}\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^N)$. Here $N$ is at least $1$, the integral is at least Caratheodory, coercive and $|f(x, z, \zeta)|\leq K|\zeta|^n$ for some $K>0$ and all $(x, z, \zeta)\in\Omega\times\mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R}^{Nn}$.

There are clearly a wide number of problems framed in the above way. I was wondering if there is an example of a *variational problem* framed in the above way that has a *non-constant continuous minimiser, $v$* and a non-constant critical point (not necessarily, but preferably continuous) $u$, that is distinct from $v$. The admissible class can be made smaller if it suits the example. I am looking for explicit examples and not existence theorems.

Comment: Consider $$ I(u)= \frac{1}{2} \int_\Omega | \nabla u|^2 + \frac{1}{4} \int_\Omega u^4 - \frac{\lambda}{2} \int_\Omega u^2$$ where $ \lambda>\lambda_1 $ (first eigenvalue of $ -\Delta $).      This should have two non-zero minimizers  and $0$ should also be a critical point...

Comment: Sorry, in the question I meant that both the critical point and the minimiser's are non-constant...Also am I correct in assuming that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ in the above example?

Comment: any dimension is fine..